# Can API stats return real revision number instead of 1234.5678?

Tags: bug, feature-request, support, status-completed

Currently it returns like this

```
"revision": "1.0.1234.5678"
```

And looks like that number never changed.

So, Can API return real revision number whenever there is an update?

It will be very useful when we do bug reports or asking for support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be ready on the next deployment of the API.

Comment: Just a note to say that this is active now.